# Ballerina: identical types are incompatible

Tags: ballerina

Using ballerina 0.991.0, I have this in my main file:

```
import ballerinax/jdbc;
import myorg/mymodule;

...

jdbc:Client myDB = new({
  url: "jdbc:postgresql:mydb",
  // etc, db properties
});

...

      result = mymodule:runQuery(myDB);
...
```

Meanwhile, in `mymodule`:

```
import ballerinax/jdbc;

...

public function runQuery (jdbc:Client db) returns json {

...
```

Trying to compile my project, I get the error message:

`error: .::my_service.bal:32:27: incompatible types: expected 'ballerinax/jdbc:0.0.0:Client', found 'ballerinax/jdbc:0.0.0:Client'`

Even if ballerina isn't able to recognize that I'm importing the exact same thing from the same module, shouldn't it recognize that the types have the same signature? How do I get around this?

Comment: This seems to be a bug. https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/17912

Comment: Thanks! At least now I know I'm not going crazy. :)